# What's the best way to retrieve single value (max date) from SQL database in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm a novice w/ c#, and I'm just trying to retrieve a single value (the max date) from an Access database using SQL through C#.  What's the best way to go about this?  The SQL string is below.  Thanks!

```
strSQL = @"SELECT MAX(TRADE_DATE) FROM tblModels WHERE [MODEL] = '" + Symbol.SymbolInformation.CompanyName + "'";
```

Comment: The way you're doing it I would imagine - the answer might change given any context.

Comment: Because this is obligatory and hasn't yet been pointed out, parameterize your query.  Please.  Two problems with adding the string directly in the query as you are, 1. what happens if CompanyName has a quote, and 2. it's susceptible to injection of malicious code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Entity Framework Core you can create a model you can map to. I usually make use of a ViewContext class to properly separate database and view models

```
public MaxTradeDate GetMaxTradeDate(string company)
{
    return ViewContext.MaxTradeDate.FromSql
    (
         $"EXEC SELECT MAX(TRADE_DATE) AS Date FROM tblModels WHERE [MODEL] = @Company",
         new SqlParameter("@Company", company)
    ).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Your model will be something like

```
public class MaxTradeDate
{
    public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
}
```

If you are separating your database and view models as indicated by the process above you should remember to add the model as a property of the ViewContext class, for example

```
public DbSet<MaxTradeDate> MaxTradeDate { get; set; }
```

Below is an example of what your ViewContext class might look like

```
public class ViewContext : DbContext
{
    public string DefaultConnectionStringName { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public DbSet<MaxTradeDate> MaxTradeDate { get; set; }

    public DatabaseContext()
    {
        DefaultConnectionStringName = "DatabaseContext";
    }

    public DatabaseContext
    (
        string defaultConnectionStringName,
        string connectionString = ""
    )
    {
        DefaultConnectionStringName = defaultConnectionStringName;

        ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConnectionString))
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
        }
        else
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(new ConnectionStringManager().Get(DefaultConnectionStringName));
        }

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2) is very straightforward. I'm not at my computer, so there may be typos, but it would be something like this...

```
string connString= // connection string to your SQL database, left as an exercise for the reader
string sql = "SELECT MAX(TRADE_DATE) FROM tblModels WHERE [MODEL] = @CompanyName";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)),
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Symbol.SymbolInformation.CompanyName;

        object scalar = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        var maxTradeDate=(DateTime)scalar; // I'm assuming trade_date is a datetime,datettime2 or date.
    }
}
```

Note the use of parameters rather than string concatenation to create queries because it prevents the code being vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

This may help get you going with connection strings for Access... https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/